# How can I generate .ipa file in flutter in android-studio..?

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

I'm *trying* to find out how generate the .ipa file in *flutter* in android studio on **MacOS**

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: Use Xcode to generate IPA.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:
open terminal and type cd "your flutter sdk path"

Step 2:
cd export PATH=/Users/yourname/Downloads/flutter/bin:$PATH

Step 3:
cd your project path

Step 4:
flutter build ios --release

run step 1 to 4 in terminal.

After that open android studio and go to iOS folder path and open project.pbxproj file with ios module and in xcode you need to choose generic ios device and select archive, it will generate ipa build for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need Xcode to generate .ipa file.

https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios